# text not displaying right hand side of the logo in html

Tags: html, css

Hi in the below code right end of the logo text want to display and all the three option in a single line.

expected output:

```
Logo                               Welcome Guest       Free Register   Login
```

can anyone help me

```css
.logo {
  float: left;
}
.logo a {
  display: block;
}
.header {
  margin: 10px 0;
}
.header-right ul li {
  width: 52%;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="logo">
      <a href="index.html">
        <img src="images/logo.gif" alt="" />
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="header-right">
      <ul>
        <li>Welcome Guest</li>
        <li>Free Register</li>
        <li>Login</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are giving `float` and `width` to every single `li`.

You want to do that to the `ul` and give `display: inline-block` to the `li`.

Something like this..

```css
.logo {
  float: left;
}
.logo a {
  display: block;
}
.header {
  margin: 10px 0;
}
.header-right ul {
  float: right;
  width: 52%;
}
.header-right ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="logo">
      <a href="index.html">
        <img src="images/logo.gif" alt="" />
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="header-right">
      <ul>
        <li>Welcome Guest</li>
        <li>Free Register</li>
        <li>Login</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/r1x6zf8p/)**

```
.header-right{
    width: 52%;
    float: right;
}

.header-right ul li {
 margin:0 20px;
   display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your styles like this:

```
.header-right ul {
  width: 52%;
 float: right;
}
.header-right ul li
{display:inline;
 margin-right:15px;
}
```